# Boxes around clickable links in .pdf TOC too long, hyperref doesn't help?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdf, links

I have difficulties with the length of boxes around clickable links in the output PDF's ToC. When a ToC entry is two lines long, the clickable link box around the second line does not indent. I have tried using the `hyperref` package, but couldn't resolve the problem. Here is an image illustrating the issue:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!:)

Comment: Somehow my "Dear all," from the top line disappeared.

Comment: Not much you can do. With xelatex e.g. it is better, as it better calculates the size of the continuation of a link, but pdflatex has no such in-built optimization and calculating it manually would be too much work. Remove the link borders so that is not visible.

Comment: Oh well. Thank you! :)